# Linear transformation of a polyhedral cone

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry

Let $C$ be a polyhedral cone in $\mathbb{R}^m$ with H- and V-representations

$C = \{x : A x \le 0 \} = \{R y : y \ge 0\}.$

The pair $(A,R)$ is referred to as a double description (DD) pair of the cone $C$.

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, $m \ge n$, be a linear transformation, and $C' = \{Tx: x \in C\}$ be the image of the cone $C$ under $T$. What is the DD pair $(A',R')$ of the resulting polyhedral cone $C'$?

Of course, $R' = TR$ and we can use this to compute $A'$ numerically. What I am after is a rather algebraic answer on how to characterize $A'$ directly in terms of $A$ and (some pseudoinverse of) $T$.

Comment: If $T$ is invertible ($m=n$), then $(A',R') = (A T^{-1}, TR)$ is a DD pair for $C'$. Otherwise, we can assume without loss of generality that $T$ is a projection. Perhaps there is no clean answer -- $A'$ now follows algorithmically from the Fourier-Motkin elimination process.

Comment: A singular $T$ can "squish" the face lattice; the $k$-dimensional faces of $TC$ come from faces of $C$ whose dimension lies in $[k, k + \dim \ker T]$.  This can happen whenever you do something linear to a polyhedron; I believe software like PPL and PORTA that does this sort of computation just bite the bullet and does Fourier-Motzkin.  (With a bunch of heuristics.)